# Media Queries and Rails Asset Pipeline

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

So I've noticed that when Rails processes it concatenates all media queries together and sticks them at the bottom of the CSS file.

Is this an option that I can disable? Is it a purposeful decision on by the asset pipeline?

Comment: Hmmmm it shouldn't modify the order you define. I just checked the assets on one of my sites and the media queries are where I put them. Can you show some code samples? I've never seen that behaviour

Comment: What css compiler/processor/minifier you using ? I use Sass and afaik it doesn't do this. Are you sure you are not compiling all your css into a single file which creates a confusion ? Also behavior in development is different than production..